# https in Cordova/Angular appears not be encrypting data?

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, https

I am possibly, just missing something obvious, but I have a Cordova + AngularJS app that I have setup to post to https://xxxxx using $http, for login/register calls, but when I run the app on the device and then "inspect devices" in chrome, I am able to see the data being sent back and forth.

My understanding is that I should not be able to view that traffic.

Is there a tool/method I can use to test if the connection is in fact secure? Or is there another method to properly secure the connection?

thanks very much

Comment: as far as I know, when you inspect from chrome you can see the data being posted. Using https only means data can't be read once it's transmited, (like somebody scanning the wifi network), but the device knows what is sending and receiving, and the inspector just tell you that.

Comment: What kind of security do you want to ensure? HTTPS secure the communication stage to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks. If you want to hide the information from the user / browser, it is another kind of thing.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the fast responses! I am not trying to hide the information from the user, but I dont want other apps installed on the device to be able to view the information. My fear is that if I can see the data from my computer when the device is plugged in, then any malicious app would be able to view it too? Or am I wrong? thanks again

Comment: the apps can only be inspected on debug mode, when you install the app from google play nobody can inspect it